How to expand JSON object from one column into many columns?
I have a table in a Postgres database that contains users, with their attributes stored as JSONB. The attributes can vary per user, and can be strings or lists of strings. Example snippets for two users:
select username, attributes from idp_accounts where username in ('visser', 'peter');
 username |                                                                  attributes                                                                  
----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 peter    | {"dn": "Peter Vonk", "sHO": "hei.foobar1.zz", "ePSA": ["student@hei.foobar1.zz", "student@hei.foobar2.zz"], "email": "peter@barz.baz"}
 visser   | {"cn": "Dick Visser", "sn": "Visser", "uid": ["visser"], "mail": ["dnmvisser@foo.com", "dick.visser@foo.org"], "displayName": "Dick Visser"}
(2 rows)

I'm looking for a way to select all attributes for a user as columns, so that the results looks like this:
ssp=> select username, ????attributes???? from idp_accounts where username = 'visser';
 username |       cn     |    sn     |   uid       |                   mail                         |  displayName
----------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------+----------------
 visser   | Dick Visser  |  Visser   | ["visser"]  |  ["dnmvisser@foo.com", "dick.visser@foo.org"]  |  Dick Visser
(1 row)

I've been over the various JSON functions but can't seem to get the result I'm looking for.

You'll have to specify the column names and types, there's no way around that. You can use jsonb_to_record(attributes), see the duplicates for examples

Actually, jsonb_populate_record() is typically the best (fastest, safest, cleanest) option. Especially with a given target table. I added a link.
